# Changing the class of a div when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript

How can I change a div class name when clicking on it? Eg:

```
<div class="first_name" onclick="changeClass();" id="first_name"></div>
```

I want to change it as follows, when a user clicks on the div

```
<div class="second_name" onclick="changeClass();"></div>
```

I wrote the JavaScript as:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  function change_autorefreshdiv(){
    var NAME = document.getElementById("first_name")
    NAME.className="second_name"
  } 
</script>
```

It's working for the first instance only. That is on page load, if I click on it, the `first_name` gets changed into `second_name`. But clicking on it again, it won't revert the `second_name` to `first_name`.

Comment: You want to also remove the `id` attribute?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to define the second class name. Currently, you have got a function which changes the class name to a hard-coded value, independent on the current class name. See also: [MDN: if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```
function change_autorefreshdiv(){
    var NAME = document.getElementById("first_name");
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (currentClass == "second_name") { // Check the current class name
        NAME.className = "first_name";   // Set other class name
    } else {
        NAME.className = "second_name";  // Otherwise, use `second_name`
    }
}
```

Comment: @user632347 If you're interested in learning basic/advanced javaScript, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 4):

A quite late answer, but the reaction marked as answer can be shortened:

```
function change_autorefreshdiv(){
     var NAME = document.getElementById("first_name");
     NAME.className = (NAME.className == "second_name") ? "first_name" : "second_name";
}
```

This is a shortened notation of the if-else structure. It checks if the `className` is equal to "second_name".
If it is, the `currentClass` variable will become "first_name", if it's not (meaning it's "first_name"),
it will become "second_name".

Answer (score 3):

simple javascript function, put it in your application.js, or script tag :-
(jQuery should be included to run the following function)

```
function changeClass(){
        $("#first_name").attr("class", "class-name-you-want-to-assign");
    }
```

Comment: you did not specify, that your solution requires jQuery, or similar framework

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no code to do so. Add a little check. I also added some semicolons. I wonder if your script would even work the first time.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function change_autorefreshdiv(){
  var NAME = document.getElementById("first_name");
  if (NAME.className==="second_name")
  {
    NAME.className="first_name";
  }
  else
  {
    NAME.className="second_name";
  }
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an `if`-statement to reverse it. Here's an example:

```
function change_autorefreshdiv(){
    var NAME = document.getElementById("first_name")
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if(currentClass == "second_name"){
        NAME.className = "first_name";
    } else {
        NAME.className = "second_name";
    }
}
```