# dynamically change css class name

Tags: css, html, asp.net-4.5

Below is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lViewMenu" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="context-menu-group"><span class="color-bar color-13"></span>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnMenu" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MenuName")%>' OnClick="lbtnMenu_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And i need to change the class name of `<li>` to **context-menu-group active** when a LinkButton is clicked on the onclick() How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript   ....... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941276/how-to-change-the-class-of-a-div-when-clicking-on-it   ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014385/javascript-jquery-to-change-class-onclick   ... have a look at these links..it may help you

Comment: I need to handle this in server side! How ?

Comment: <li class="context-menu-group" onclick="this.className='context-menu-group active'"> ... The above code changing the class name but it agains come to the original class after refresh..

Comment: Why have you said you need to do it server side and then proceeded to show an example of clientside?

Comment: Save it into a cookie if somebody clicked and check if the cookie is present on every load... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp