# Display text messages in HTML -- with boxes

Tags: html

Can some one suggest how to display this type of message chat in html where messages are shown in boxes in left & right of screen ..?

Boxes are shown in blue & green colour

[image: General example - of chat]

Comment: I just want to know how to display these boxes in blue & light-green color .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give some clues so you can work on it, I think it can help you:

HTML code:

```
<div class="blue_box">
    <span>Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="green_box">
    <span>Bye</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue_box, .green_box {
    display: block;
    clear:both;
}
.blue_box span {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
.green_box span {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope it helps,

here is a fiddle to see it running.

http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/2/

Comment: can i change class of a div at run time ... ?

Comment: You can, using Javascript, here are some topic about it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941276/changing-the-class-of-a-div-when-clicking-on-it or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-div-tag

Comment: Thanks for answering ... one more thing is it possible to round the corner of box and also add a pointed shape along the vertical wall (using css ) ... as shown in the image i posted ... it will give it an apperance of a chat box ..?

Comment: For the round border I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/3/ with border-radius prperty.
For the pointed shape you can make some research here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237181/how-to-add-bordered-triangle-over-a-div-tag

Comment: Thanks ... i tried by using reference of link inside the link you posted .. http://cssarrowplease.com/  .. my results are here .. its not as per expectation  http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/6/  ... arrow is not coming on right ... please suggest where i am getting wrong... ?

Comment: Edited the auto generated css code from http://cssarrowplease.com/.... arrow is coming very big at the right .. http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/7/

Comment: Ok, it's done, although the CSS it's a little bit messy, try to read it, understand it and make it cleaner:

http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/8/

Regards

Comment: thanks its complicated but i will try to understand it.

Comment: just one last support from you... how to add top padding between the two message boxes ... see here bye & one are joined together ..  http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/12/ ..how to add space between both messages as in the attached image. I also tried to insert horizontal line but lines are not coming at right order.

Comment: if i use property padding-top : 20px; .. it increases the size of the box not the spacing between the boxes ... http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/13/

Comment: this one worked .. http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/14/  ... is it right way i think .. ?

Comment: I don't know if you want the <hr> or not, but you can use an empty div, i called it space to get the job done. Hope it solves your problem!

http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/15/

Comment: Thanks it also works.. last thing i m trying is to put an date time when the message is written.. http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/16/  ... is it possible to show time stamp in smaller text size .. along the message in box or ... on the left of the screen for right arrow box  & on the right of the screen for left arrow box ... ?

Comment: Here is my code for that: http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/17/

This is getting out of the main question I think. Maybe opening a new thread would be a nice idea, as we a touching javascript right now.

Comment: thanks it's done ... here is what i edited code from yours ..  http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/19/

Comment: Glad you make it, nice work, could you mark this answer as useful? it would help me too. Regards

Comment: I mark your answer useful, pleease suggest on this last point from my side.
I am able to add the padding to the left & right of time stamp
using ... padding-right : 50px;

At present message boxes are very much close to left & right end of Html page.
But i want it to be little away from left & right of the webpage.
But i am not able to add padding to the boxes using..  padding-right : 50px; or  padding-left : 50px; .. adding padding to right box increases the box size ... http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/21/

Comment: i am able to add padding to timestamp .. but not to the arrow box ... http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/22/

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/54vgn2um/23/

Use left / right attribute.

By the way, you vote one of my comments as useful, not the answer...